# Is there a means to disable Typesafe Activator UI

Tags: sbt, typesafe-activator

I have created a project and I want to prevent the user from starting the activator UI by accident and generating tons of files that it generates. Is there a property I can set or some other means? I read the documentation abotu the benefits of activator over SBT and I don't want to re-litigate that, I just want it to disable certain features.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, no. The UI is started when the user types `activator ui`, and I think it's a fair assumption that users don't type `ui` by accident.

Also, I don't think `activator ui` generates files, certainly not tons. What files are you referring to?

Activator is open source. You could fork https://github.com/typesafehub/activator and provide a modified version to your users. For example you could (I haven't tried, by I assume) delete line https://github.com/typesafehub/activator/blob/master/launcher/src/main/scala/activator/ActivatorLauncher.scala#L81 to prevent Activator from displaying its docs in the browser when started in a non-project directory.

Lastly, you may want to reconsider just using plain sbt.  [`sbt new`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/sbt-new-and-Templates.html) is the new recommended way to create projects from templates, replacing Activator.

Comment: Recommended by who? Lightbend?

Comment: That's my understanding, yes.